# What does Typo3 CMS offer (or can do) that WordPress 4 doesn't?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, compare, open-source, typo3

This is not an opinion based question but rather a technical limits comparison one.

From the [various](http://www.vcat.de/en/open-source/typo3-wordpress-potsdam/typo3-programmierung-berlin.html) comparison charts about the two CMS I couldn't really find any technical difference between the two platforms. Being a long time WordPress developer I find the supplied arguments about [Typo3 technical pros](http://typo3.org/typo3-cms/key-features/) exist somehow in WordPress; Everything you could achieve in one can be achieved in the other as well (plugins & extensions).

Let's take for example the latest versions of both two CMS's, what does Typo3 can do that WordPress can't even with its plugins/extensions?

**UPDATE**

Please instead of down voting the question, provide at least 1 reason for your vote.

Comment: If one does not hate to use `the_magic()` and `get_the_magic()` way of "developing", then WP is fine. If you hate it and favor clean OOP code, separation of template and application logic, like structured database tables, config in files instead of db (portability) then WP might not suit your needs while TYPO3 does. Technically spoken. (Hint: "clean" OOP code is not true for the whole TYPO3, though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you write, the technical pros exist *somehow* in WordPress.

I personally think a major advantage of TYPO3 is the extension framework `extbase` and the template rendering engine `fluid`. 
Developing (and maintaining) larger extensions becomes a lot easier since their introduction as well as an overall cleaner, fully object oriented code base.

3rd party extension written in that technology are easier to adapt/customize than some extensions in Wordpress which sometimes mix procedural with object oriented style.

Webpages with multiple languages are easier to handle in TYPO3 (e.g. content fallback), which makes it more interesting for bigger projects.

Take a look at the [TYPO3 showcases](http://www.t3blog.com/) and the [Wordpress showcases](https://wordpress.org/showcase/), to me it looks like Wordpress is primarily used for subsites (like blogs, landingpages etc.) whereas TYPO3 is used more for corporate sites (which probably have a longer life cycle).

Comment: I agree on the fact that "Wordpress which sometimes mix procedural with object oriented style" but this is due to the developers and not imposed by WP itself. WordPress has the filters and actions that allows to hook and extend core functions... WordPress used to be for blogs but now u can do advanced websites with it like; webshops for example..

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is opinion base question, so there's my opinion (not an answer).

TYPO3 from the very beginning was considered as a *Content Management Framework* (that means CMS with possibilities of further custom development) while WordPress was *just a blog*. Of course with time things changed, as more and more people tried use the WP to doing more serious things.  Anyway in WP the main disadvantage till now is "blog way of thinking" - in TYPO3 you have open structure - building services on the unlimited nested tree, while WordPress (probably) is still basing on the primitive structures, category/post/site (note, I'm not familiar with WP, so maybe there are some workarounds for this now).

You should install TYPO3 and compare the way how you put the content on the pages, how you can control the access for both FE and BE users and also such things like *versioning* workflow. with all my sympathy to WP I'm almost sure that's not so easy to do such things in it.

Also starting extensions with Extension Builder is just matter of minutes, so it allows you to deliver solutions to your clients exactly in the way as they want.

Conclusion, from my POV I wouldn't choose WordPress for most of my clients (car producers, publishing houses, building developers) on the other hand last time when I was asked by cellogue of mine for creating typical blog with TYPO3 I did it ... with WordPress and he's satisfied with it, me too.

As my partner used to say: "*CMS is just a hammer, it depends on requirements which size you should choose*"

Comment: I think you posted your opinion instead of showing the technical differences/challenges; all the "pros" you mentioned (open structure, control the access for both FE and BE, versioning workflow, Extensions..) exist already in WordPress 4.

Comment: I accented that's opinion at very beginning, also mentioned that I have no full knowledge of the current WP version. Sorry topic is too broad to be described here